# Python App Engine SDK only loads default module

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an App Engine app contains 3 modules and a dispatch.yaml. It works perfectly in production, however on the dev server (using GAE Launcher) only the default module is loaded.

The command which is run by the launcher:

```
Running command: "['D:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=10081', '--admin_port=8002', 'D:\\path\\to\\my\\app']"
```

I know that when running `dev_appserver.py` using the command line it is possible to specify all modules as arguments. Is there a way of doing it when using the Launcher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is done the same way as you do for an IDE like PyCharm, where you pass the yaml files (for each module) in the Extra Flags section.

1. Double-click the instance in App Engine Launcher
2. Under Extra Flags, add all the yaml files for your modules, separated by a space "app.yaml app2.yaml app3.yaml"

Comment: I was hoping that a better solution exists out there... But thanks anyway.

Comment: I agree, you'd think launcher would support modules better since App Engine moved away from backends!

Comment: This is just working for the local development instance, did this work for you for deploying as well?

Answer (score 2):

[Bardia's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4024111/bardia-d) answer is correct. However, after experiencing the problem myself and speaking with a GAE support engineer, I've added some further details. This information is currently missing from the [official GAE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/), but Google are planning to add it soon.

To use Google App Engine Launcher to 'Run' or 'Deploy' an application that uses modules you first need to:

1. Double click the application in Google App Engine Launcher, to bring up the Application Settings window.
2. Under Extra Flags, list the yaml files separated by spaces. Specify the full file path. If you are using a routing file, dispatch.yaml, list it first. Don't include app.yaml as this is already included by default.

e.g. /Users/.../dispatch.yaml /Users/.../app2.yaml /Users/.../app3.yaml

There is also a blog post, which explains how to do it, here:

http://www.shiftedup.com/2014/11/11/running-modules-locally-using-the-googleappenginelauncher-application

**Update**

[Yaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/514977/yaron) commented that this method only works when you click the 'Run' button to run on localhost, but it doesn't work when you click 'Deploy' to deploy to production. I checked and I had the same problem, so I contacted Google support. They advised me that Google App Engine Launcher is now archived and is no longer supported. Instead we should use the new '[gcloud preview app deploy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/preview/app/deploy)' command.

To deploy multiple modules, type the following into the command line:

```
gcloud preview app deploy ~/my_app/app.yaml \ 
~/my_app/another_module.yaml
```

Which is a shame, because I quite liked Google App Engine Launcher.

Comment: This is just working for the local development instance, did this work for you for deploying as well?

Comment: Yaron, we use appcfg to deploy:  python /usr/local/google_appengine/appcfg.py -e foo@gmail.com update .